# IInAppBillingService stuck in purchasing overlay

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have InAppPurchases, I created service with

```
mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
```

and bind it with

```
Intent serviceIntent =
                new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        context.bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

then I start purchasing with

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("android_id", MainApplication.getInstance().android_id);
            jsonObject.put("user_id", userId);
            jsonObject.put("email", userEmail);

            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, context.getPackageName(),
                    purchasingItemId, "inapp", jsonObject.toString());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

            if (pendingIntent != null) {
                fragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        MainApplication.ACTIVITY_RESULT_REQUEST_KEY.IN_APP_BILLING_PURHASING_RESPONSE,
                        new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                        Integer.valueOf(0));
            }
```

It's working ok, I see white card with preloader - then purchasing info, click `ok`, see again white card with preloader and then white card with `Purchase successful`, BUT if I minimize app before I'll see purchasing info or `Purchase successful` (when preloader is spinning) and then open it again - I see infinite preloader and nothing happens, back button does not work (but purchase is successful and user gets his items in background) and only way to get rid of it - is relaunch app

This is how it looks - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIZhq.jpg

Why is this happening and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Here one possible solution:

add a flag in `InAppPurchase` controller which launches your in-app purchase intents

```
public volatile boolean inAppFragmentOpened = false;
```

and set it to `true` just before sending the intent and set it to `false` when the purchase is over

then, in `Activity`'s method `onStart()` add this check

```
    if (InAppBillingFacade.getInstance().inAppFragmentOpened) {
        InAppBillingFacade.getInstance().inAppFragmentOpened = false;
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

This will relaunch you app if an opened `In-App purchase` window is present on start  - it can help avoid glitches and freezes on it, but still, maybe someone knows a better solution?